# GORM Associations Preload not work with primary key ID int = 0

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have two models below

```
type Bot struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name           string
  ExchangeID     uint
  Exchange       Exchange
}

type Exchange struct {
  gorm.Model
  Image        string
  Status       string
}
```

It means a Bot belongs to an Exchange.

In my database, i have a row with id = 0 in table "exchanges" and many rows with exchange_id = 0 in table "bots".

The issue is that Preload in Bot queries not work for rows that have exchange_id = 0. It works well with rows that have exchange_id = 1,2,3...

Has anyone met this issue? I think it's gorm issue with special value 0. I'm working around by declaring ExchangeId in Bot and Id in Exchange as string but it has some tradeoffs.

Comment: Do you have GORM tags in your structs? I think you need to add `gorm:"foreignKey:ExchangeID"` to your `Exchange` field in the `Bot` struct.

Comment: @ThijsvanderHeijden unnecessary since my models followed gorm conventions. btw, i'm wondering if the issue is related to underlying mysql schema